# Check for a specific value in a table python

Tags: python, authentication

I am trying to make a login script check for a verified email the check script is

```
#check for verification
            while True:
                if "'emailVerified': True" in accountinfo:
                    break
                else:
                    print("Your email has not been verified! Please verify it with the new link we have sent.")
                    auth.send_email_verification(user['idToken'])
                    menu()
```

The value in the table I am trying to find is

> 'emailVerified': True

It keeps saying it can not find it though the value is there. How do I make it look for that? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: can you `print accountinfo`

Comment: @LeiYang `{'kind': 'identitytoolkit#GetAccountInfoResponse', 'users': [{'localId': 'JdXSs6uCbzSYCOPDNf3Xan2CAvf2', 'email': 'testaccount@gmail.com', 'passwordHash': 'UkVEQUNURUQ=', 'emailVerified': False, 'passwordUpdatedAt': 1624584912403, 'providerUserInfo': [{'providerId': 'password', 'federatedId': 'testaccount@gmail.com', 'email': 'testaccount@gmail.com', 'rawId': 'testaccount@gmail.com'}], 'validSince': '1624584912', 'lastLoginAt': '1624584912403', 'createdAt': '1624584912403', 'lastRefreshAt': '2021-06-25T01:35:13.096Z'}]}`

Comment: it shows `'emailVerified': False`, so the actual problem is lying elsewhere.

Comment: oh sorry wait that was a test account pretend it did say true the  only difference is it not saying "True" instead of false

Comment: What's `type(accountinfo)`. It may be a dictionary in which case your if condition is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user validation logic is not very clear. But if you simply ask why `emailVerified: True` is in `accountinfo`, but `if "'emailVerified': True" in accountinfo` always gets `False`. The answer is they are different types. The left is a string, the right is a dictionary(or json).

Can you try this function:

```
def is_any_user_email_verified(accountinfo):
    return any(u for u in accountinfo['users'] if u['emailVerified'])

# usage:
if is_any_user_email_verified(accountinfo):
    break
```

Comment: perfect ... until you found a issue. please try to get to understand each field in `accountinfo`, you'll learn useful things from that.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to use the string `"'emailVerified': True"` as a key to the `accountinfo` dictionary object (representing an account's info I think).

The think the best way to do it would be to do this:

```
while True:
            if accountinfo['users'][0]['emailVerified']:
                break
            else:
                print("Your email has not been verified! Please verify it with the new link we have sent.")
                auth.send_email_verification(user['idToken'])
                menu()
```

Although this is **quite bad** and the structure of your accountinfo object is convoluted. I think you should either split it up into two objects or just unpack the lists into key value pairs for the entire accountinfo object. I would avoid having to use [0] (or having to use [i]) to index the List within the dictionary object, which has *ANOTHER* dictionary in it! That is very confusing hierarchy of python objects.

You should try to change the accountinfo object to allow this:

```
while True:
            if accountinfo['emailVerified']:
                break
            else:
                print("Your email has not been verified! Please verify it with the new link we have sent.")
                auth.send_email_verification(user['idToken'])
                menu()
```

Comment: the `accountinfo` should be from some framework, not the OP. otherwise he shouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: @LeiYang Oh okay, I just assumed it was their own since the conditional was so strange. Should I take this answer down?

Comment: np. i think your answer is meaningful and helpful! we're both beginners of stackoverflow :)